# Looking for a few good examples of the Javascript Class in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Im having a hard time understanding how to utilize the javascript class in CodeIgniter 2.

What I would like to see is some good use of loading jquery, binding to selectors, ajax and lastly... Using this in a templating system that leverages one header.

Any good pointers or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, I've never seen anything I'd consider a good use of this library - in fact I voted to remove it altogether on uservoice (it's the second biggest library/driver in CI, next to the Email class, and IMO the least useful). Looking forward to a good answer if it exists.

Answer (score -2):

you can create a `header.php` on your view, on your controller you would have to call

```
<?php

class Page extends CI_Controller {

   function index()
   {
      $data['page_title'] = 'Your title';
      $this->load->view('header');
      $this->load->view('content', $data);
      $this->load->view('footer');
   }

}
?>
```

You will need the header and footer on every controller you create,

on you `header.php` OR `footer.php` depends how you wish to utilise your javascript...

```
<script src="[jquery url]"></script>
<script src="">
   $(document).ready(){
       $('div').hide(2500);
       $('a').click(function (){
            $('p').load('ajax');
       });
   });
</script>
```

**content.php**

```
<div>I will hide away soon enough (~2.5 seconds)</div>
<a href="#">Click Here</a>
<p>Your ajax content will go here once you click link above</p>
```

======
as for your ajax you can do it from your controller

```
<?php

class Page extends CI_Controller {

   function ajax()
   {
      $json['error'] = '';
      $json['error'] = '';
      echo json_encode($json);
     /// or if you want html back//
      $data['page_title'] = 'Your title 2';
      $this->load->view('ajax', $data);//ajax.php on your view
   }

}
?>
```

Your ajax.php then should have something you could use ...

Comment: I dont see where your using the CI Javascript library... Am I missing something?

Comment: CI javascript library where did you get that from? CI it's just the name of a php class http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html as given by code igniter on the link, the above are guide lines "as your question was very vague"

Comment: Your falling behind the times!   http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/javascript.html

Comment: oh tuche lol, my bad, well its all experimental, and they say it may change, also it's a silly idea, as then not only you would have to know how jquery works, but also how codeigniter has reinvented the wheel, your better of using the view and you have more flexibility there :)

Comment: 1. http://choosedaily.com/1052/9-ways-to-integrate-ajax-with-codeigniter/  2. http://www.mrforbes.com/blog/2009/01/a-quick-code-igniter-and-jquery-ajax-tutorial/